# Docker push "requested access to the resource is denied"

Tags: docker

I've seen other threads of this error on Stack Overflow and so far nothing has resolved it.

I'm building an image and tagging it with my username/repo name:

`docker build -t myusername/company-snapshot:sometag .`

Verifying with `docker images`:

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myusername/company-snapshot    sometag   71857cd2e7b5   22 minutes ago   1.76GB
welcome-to-docker              latest    2550d1bae2b8   30 hours ago     226MB
```

I login successfully, I've tried including `docker.io` at the end and not including it, it doesn't seem to make a difference:

`docker login -u "myusername" -p "mypass"`

I push the image:

`docker push myusername/company-snapshot:sometag`

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/myusername/company-snapshot]
21feca696540: Preparing 
b1276b6f3640: Preparing 
8fc8c8cab8d8: Preparing 
24d5aa2cf6a5: Preparing 
e702fa99e63f: Preparing 
66356a5b199e: Preparing 
02e47744d215: Preparing 
3a306931dcab: Preparing 
b4119a8c1610: Waiting 
067d0e354961: Waiting 
3f02bc5c0f6e: Waiting 
89652c2242d7: Waiting 
66356a5b199e: Waiting 
17e090f6763f: Waiting 
f232a0c9e2f9: Waiting 
3a306931dcab: Waiting 
59f5637ef6cf: Waiting 
b93c96367f9e: Waiting 
983539bcc7fd: Waiting 
bf54e1736db7: Waiting 
a949bdd10bd5: Waiting 
b5c82167dfee: Waiting 
d95d62a4c4f3: Waiting 
7ec7185e1d35: Waiting 
5f70bf18a086: Waiting 
a0a490ba5396: Waiting 
b91c0a8b447f: Waiting 
2499d4495201: Waiting 
d323d3bc96eb: Waiting 
cfce7a3c5acf: Waiting 
5a3d378c3f8b: Waiting 
740d0884a9e9: Waiting 
ff52e8984463: Waiting 
8cc69581f54c: Waiting 
e3410ef7b630: Waiting 
6825249d299e: Waiting 
69630d4fd98d: Waiting 
04f184c4c6b5: Waiting 
d71512bd967d: Waiting 
d4a52c422bff: Waiting 
4b62d4bcbe36: Waiting 
c43782c41a27: Waiting 
67ec02949dcc: Waiting 
8e87ff28f1b5: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

One person found that they needed to update Docker desktop, but mine is updated.

Answer (score 0):

So what finally worked is doing everything with sudo. `sudo docker build`, `sudo docker login` and then `sudo docker push`.